# Pan Images Toward Mouse Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I program the effect seen on this site http://www.madwell.com/ where the images move slightly in the direction of the mouse?

Comment: Got any code to show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mousemove` and play with the parameters and transitions.

Here's a very basic example:
https://jsfiddle.net/r0kzc2mw/1/

Comment: Nice, that's what I was trying to do.